# To match only the word mentioned as table_name in below

Tags: regex

I am using a command:

```
/usr/bin/sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE `table_name`/,/CREATE TABLE/p' dump.sql
```

to get selected table from all database dump.

It is working but I am getting output for other tables as well which are like:

table_nameabc,table_namexyz

As I am expecting only output for word table_name.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, but from what you've told:

```
grep -w 'CREATE TABLE table_name' dump.sql
```

should help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Above will work fine to get the line CREATE TABLE table_name. But I want the table structure with data I mean create table info and insert info for the table .

Comment: paste some example input/output pls.(in your question) @Gopal

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

```
/usr/bin/sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE table_name/!h; /CREATE TABLE/{x;p}' dump.sql
```

Comment: with above cpmmand I am getting output like 
CREATE TABLE abc (
CREATE TABLE abctest ( 
CREATE TABLE abcxyz (

and so on but I am expecting output [table create info and insert info ]only for table abc not for others.